# issue with edit input string type matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I got an error:

```
Error using edit (line 31)
The input must be a string.

Error in showTF>callback_update_model (line 507)
    vars.dropheight = str2num(get(edit(2),'String'));
```

My code here:

```
params = varargin{1};
```

this is one of the 2 inputs:

```
edit(2) = uicontrol('Parent',jCalc,'Units','Pixels','Position',[300 20 100 20],'String',num2str(params(2)),'Style','edit',...
            'Callback',@edit_2,...
            'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'ToolTipString','Puck Drop Height');
```

button callback:

```
function callback_update_model(~,~)
    vars.dropheight = str2num(get(edit(2),'String'));
    vars.armradius = str2num(get(edit(1),'String'));
    kiddies = get(guiel.hAX(3),'Children');
    delete(kiddies); 
    clear kiddies;
    set(guiel.tfPanel,'Visible','off','Position',cnst.tfPanelpos);
    set(guiel.hAX(1),'Position',cnst.axpos1);

    if ishandle(guiel.hAX(2)) 
    set(guiel.hAX(2),'Position',cnst.axpos2);
    end
    eval(get(guiel.hPB(4),'Callback'));
end
```

the varargin shows `1X1 cell [2]` which I am confused how I am converting the input values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have used `edit` as a variable, but it is also a [built-in function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/edit.html) that expects a file name as a string input, hence your error. You should avoid shadowing built-in functions like this since it generally leads to problems and ambiguities.

Usually, the variable will take [precedence](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) and be used instead of the shadowed function. In this case, the function appears to be getting called with an input of `2` instead of the variable being indexed with `2`. This may be because the `callback_update_model` function may not have access to the `edit` variable. Here's what you should do to fix this:

1. Change the name of the variable to something like `hEdit` (I usually preface variables that store [handle graphics objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) with `h`).
2. Check that `callback_update_model` is properly [nested](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) so that it has access to `hEdit`, or provide `hEdit` to it [in another way](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html).

Comment: just realized it's not a proper nested function! Thank you.